# Android default Email app not support html tag

Tags: android, email

I am developing to send html text through default email app but It's only support in gmail not default email app. My code is below and also i attached result. Advance in thanks.

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml("<b>Android</b>"));
    activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Email Result
[image: Email]

Gmail Result
[image: Gmail]

Comment: try this : setType("text/html");

Comment: It's give error like android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=text/html (has extras) }

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       sendMail(this,"demo@demo.com","demo subject","demo text body for email <h1>This is heading 1</h1>\n" +
               "<h2>This is heading 2</h2>\n" +
               "<h3>This is heading 3</h3>\n" +
               "<h4>This is heading 4</h4>\n" +
               "<h5>This is heading 5</h5>\n" +
               "<h6>This is heading 6</h6>");
}

private void sendMail(Context context,String id, String subject,String body) {
        String[] to = id.toString().split(",");
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/html");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, no email clients are installed on your device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}    

Note : Gave this permission AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: But it's every time shows Toast even gmail also not open by this code.

Comment: have you check in device ?

Comment: It's all time give error i have check in samsung galaxy s4 and also sony xperia. both have same behave

Comment: same behave now it's support only gmail not default email application